# Intel icc compiler -O flags and -qopt-report

Tags: intel, icc

I am working on a HPC at the moment, and I have a question regarding the icc compiler.

What I want to do is to have a peek at what is going on when I change the optimisation levels through [O0..O3]. The data I want, regarding vectorization and whether code was folded inline etc., seems to be in the report generated by the `-qopt-report` flag.

I decided to use the greatest level of verbosity for the report which is

```
-qopt-report5  (I think this is the correct way to use it)
```

however, when reducing the O-level, the report gets progressively smaller until becoming empty when using the `-O0` flag:

```
icc -O0 -qopt-report5 -c test1.c
```

I'll keep looking, but if anyone notices me being brain dead, I'd appreciate a pointer to the use of these flags together!

Thanks in advance for any hints.
Cheers,
MArk.

Answer (score 2):

-qopt-report5 is always **disabled** when you use -**O0**. 
This is **"by definition"**, because opt-report == "optimization report" and O0 == "no optimization", so there is *nothing to report about*.

Auto-vectorization is generally speaking enabled starting from O2 optimizaiton level, so if you want to explore vectorization aspects, then you need to use at least "-O2 -opt-report5" combination or "higher".

If you want to correlate performance "peaks" and "optimization report", consider using Intel "Vectorization Advisor" (read more [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vectorization-advisor-faq), download from this location for now: https://software.intel.com/en-us/advisor_getting_started_intro )[image: opt-report diagnostics and many other vectorization characteristics in Advisor]

Comment: Thank you sir.  This is my first time with this compiler.  The node I am working on at the moment only has command line, so no X tools or Windows.  At the risk of sounding more foolish, is vec-report[n] still the best way to discover if code has been folded in-line?

Comment: -opt-report5 will give you maximum amount of info, including inlining. If inlining is somehow most important for you, consider -opt-report-phase (exact usage depends on Compiler version which you use; for fresh Intel Compilers (15.x or newer) take a look here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/525003 , for older ones: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/compiler_qrg12.pdf).

Comment: Regarding X tools, Advisor (as well as similar tools in Parallel Studio) supports usage model, where you collect data on cluster node, but view it on separate host (or on laptop) with GUI subsystem.    However specifically for inlinng - I would prefer to directly use opt-report, although I don't know why exactly it's important to you

Comment: Final comment: in recent ICC/IFORT versions - it's better to use opt-report (and it's variants like opt-report-phase) for everything. vec-report is relatively obsolete, although I don't think it's deprecated so far.